# PowerDesigner Pre- & Post-SQL

Tags: mysql, powerdesigner

Currently working on designing and rendering my database (the base part) in PowerDesigner 16.5 and I was wondering if it is possible to include some pre- & post sql.

What I want to do is a DROP, CREATE and USE database statement and some basic insterts for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a copy of the standard MySQL `DBMS` (`Tools > Resources > DBMS...`, `New`, `Copy from` "MySQL"), attach it to your model `Database > Change current DBMS` and edit it with `Database < Edit current DBMS` to enable the `Database` object.